# java.io.IOException: A connection established by software on your host computer has been dropped

Tags: java, html, html5-audio, vaadin8

when I do a seek on an audio, this expcetion pops up. The expcetion is triggered when the audio exceeds 7 MB . Any idea? I 'm using Vaadin 8, so audio is an HTML audio/video element.

---

```
 23:09:41,971 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-21) : java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host.
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:162)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:647)
        at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:166)
        at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:128)
        at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:219)
        at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:158)
        at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:179)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2064)
        at org.xnio.channels.Channels.writeBlocking(Channels.java:152)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeTooLargeForBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:197)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:145)
        at com.vaadin.server.DownloadStream.writeResponse(DownloadStream.java:307)
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractMedia.handleConnectorRequest(AbstractMedia.java:129)
        at com.vaadin.server.ConnectorResourceHandler.handleRequest(ConnectorResourceHandler.java:90)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:221)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
        at perseo.ui.ForwardFilter.doFilter(ForwardFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at perseo.ui.CustomShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomShiroFilter.java:23)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

### This is call hierarchy of the code:
A thread which runs a while and calls update, who tryes to access to the UI ir order to keep the playback and the view sinchronized

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
                update();
```

---

```
@Override
    public void update() {
        if (ui == null || !ui.isAttached() || ui.isClosing()) {
        } else {
            ui.access( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     // some stuff and seekAudio() eventually
```

---

```
private synchronized void seekAudio(double secs, String id) {

Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("{" + "document.getElementById('" + id + "').load();}");  // problems without this !!!!!
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("{" + "document.getElementById('" + id + "').currentTime = "+secs+";}");

Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("{" + "document.getElementById('"
            + id + "').playbackRate = "+ speed +";}");
```

}

Comment: I can comment the  load() line, but the expection remains eventually

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is that your audio file is bigger than your container allows to serve. The `Audio` component in Vaadin 8 is rather simple and attempts to load the whole file at once. There are two alternatives to fix the issue.

The one I recommend to you is to use [AudioVideo](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/audiovideo) component from Vaadin's directory. It has the replacement components for `Audio` and `Video`, which add some features, most importantly range request support. This means, that browser needs to only to load small buffer of audio at the time, and when you seek to other place in long audio stream, it fetches the audio right from the position without need to load the whole audio stream before getting to that position.

Another alternative is to find in your container settings how to allow bigger files to be served. However, this wont improve the usability in the way the first option does.